# postgresql内でyyyymmddHHMM形式の数字羅列(文字型)を'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI'の文字型に変換して抽出したい

Tags: postgresql

前回のpostgresql質問に似てますが解決しなかったので質問です。
時間を表すカラム内の値「202007101010」
このようにyyyymmddhhMI形式で刻まれた数値の文字列を
'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI'の文字型に変換して抽出したいと考えています。

202007101010が変換前であれば変換後には2020-07-10 10:10という値になります。

### 試したコード

```
select to_timestamp(yyyymmddhh24miの数字列が格納されたカラム名,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') from テーブル名;
```

### 発生しているエラー

```
ERROR:  value for "YYYY" in source string is out of range
DETAIL:  Value must be in the range -2147483648 to 2147483647.
```

フォーマッティング関数など探しましたがどう当てはめればよいか解りませんでした。
解る方いましたらご教授お願いします。

Comment: 「抽出した後に変換」ではなく、「指定のフォーマットで抽出したい」ということでしょうか？

Comment: はい、同じchar型でYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MIのように整形したいだけになります。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`to_timestamp`](https://www.postgresql.jp/document/12/html/functions-formatting.html)は日付文字列を**第二引数の文字列フォーマット**でtimestamp型に変換するものです。
なので一旦文字列を`YYYYMMDDHH24MI`フォーマットでtimestamp型に置換した後に、`to_char`の**第二引数の文字列フォーマット**の文字列に変換する2段階の処理が必要となります。

```
select to_char(to_timestamp('202007101010', 'YYYYMMDDHH24MI'), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI')
```

Comment: 感謝・私は新たなキーワードを使い、あなたの知っている情報の参照先を見つける。

Answer (score 2):

正規表現を使った文字列置換の例です。

```
select REGEXP_REPLACE('202007142025', '(....)(..)(..)(..)(..)', '\1-\2-\3 \4:\5');
```

結果

```
  regexp_replace
------------------
 2020-07-14 20:25
(1 row)
```